# Hangfire: Check the status of Windows service

Tags: hangfire

We have created hangfire background job as the windows service.

Sometimes what happens is the windows service goes down with some reason or the other as its a shared server.

I wanted to know if there is any way to check the state of the windows service from hangfire to see if the service is running fine or down. So that we can raise alerts that the service is down. Or if there is any possibility to change the status when the service goes down.

But issue is how to get the state of the windows service here.

Would appreciate inputs.